# How to run function on JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to run function sent as parameter on JavaScript, for example I create this script, I want from this script to print "successful test" but the script print the whale function as text.
Thus, how can I run a function sent as parameter to the function?

```
test=function (p1) {
        return p1;             
    }
var result=test(function(){
    return "successful test";
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: you want to `return p1();`

Comment: I want to return the result of p1

Comment: yes that is correct - that is what you need to change your code to `return p1()` rather than `return p1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should return `return p1();`

```
var test=function (p1) {
        return p1();             
    }
var result=test(function(){
    return "successful test";
});
console.log(result);
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wwrakcn1/)

Answer (score 2):

the code should be like this:

```
test=function (p1) {
        return p1;             
    }

var result=test(function(){
    return "successful test";
}());


console.log(result);
```

Comment: I like this because it doesn't force `p1` to be a function. It's self calling so it resolves to a standard variable.

Answer (score 1):

## Explanation

To invoke a function passed as a parameter to another function in javascript, you can simple invoke it using the parenthesis as usual.

```
function myFunction(callback) {
   return callback();
}
```

However, you can also use the function prototype methods [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

## Example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>

<body>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      return 'success <br />';
    }

    function simpleInvocation(fn) {
      document.write('<h1>simple</h1>');
      return fn();
    }

    function callInvocation(fn) {
      document.write('<h1>call</h1>');
      return fn.call(this);
    }

    function applyInvocation(fn) {
      document.write('<h1>apply</h1>');
      return fn.apply(this);
    }

    document.write(simpleInvocation(myFunction));

    document.write(callInvocation(myFunction));

    document.write(applyInvocation(myFunction));
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```